# Set a 1d Matrix Pattern Equal to a 2d Matrix

Tags: c++, c, matrix

I have a 2d matrix created with the code:

```
for(i=0; i < size; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j <size; j++)
    {
        a1[i][j] = i+1 + j+2;
    }
}
```

I am trying to replicate that pattern in a matrix created by:

```
double*
a = malloc(sizeof(double)*randk*randk);
```

I can't seem to figure out how to define that same pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean creating the same numeric pattern? That's just:

```
for(int i = 0; i < randk; ++i)
  for(int j = 0; j < randk; ++j)
    a[i * randk + j] = i + j + 3;
```

Or if you prefer a single loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < randk * randk; ++i)
  a[i] = (i / randk) + (i % randk) + 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

From the comp.lang.c FAQ:

[How can I dynamically allocate a multidimensional array?](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html)

Comment: Im not trying to dynamically allocate a multidimensional array...i need a single array that generates the same number patter.

Comment: That FAQ entry still applies.  If you allocate a multidimensional array as they describe, you can continue using `a1[i][j]` as before.  Or if you must use a 1-dimensional array, that FAQ entry explains how to access elements.  Read the whole thing.